# How to access and control the char *** in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a c API looks like following:

```
int enumDataFormat(char ***SampleNames);
```

### Swift Code:

```
var formats =  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>.alloc(1)
let count = enumDataFormat(&formats)
for index in 0..<count {
    //Question in here: I don't known how to access memory in Swift
}
```

### Objective-C Code:

It is working very well!

```
char **formats;
int count = enumDataFormat(&formats);
if (count > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        //obtain the string from memory
        char *formatString = *(formats + i);
        NSLog(@"%s", formatString);
    }
}
```

> Question: In Swift, how to access strings in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `alloc()`, just a variable of the type "pointer to
pointer to Int8", similar as in the (Objective-)C code:

```
var formats : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = nil
let count = Int(enumDataFormat(&formats))
```

And you can access the i'th C string pointer simply with subscript notation ...

```
for i in 0 ..< count {

    let formatString = formats[i]
```

... and convert that to a Swift string with

```
    if let format = String.fromCString(formatString) {
        println(format)
    } else {
        // Not a valid UTF-8 string.
    }
}
```

Comment: So Great! Thanks for your answering. the UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> Is it act as [Int8] right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do pointer arithmetic in Swift using UnsafePointers like this:

```
let oldPointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>()
let newPointer = oldPointer + 10
```

It creates offset of 10 bytes.

[image]

Comment: What does you means about oldPointer? Is it in for-loop?